# Queue with notifications on isEmpty() changes

Tags: java, concurrency, queue, scheduling

I have an `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`(taken from `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`) in producer-consumer environment. There is one thread adding tasks to the queue, and a thread pool executing them.

I need notifications on two events:

1. First item added to empty queue
2. Last item removed from queue

Notification = writing a message to database.

Is there any sensible way to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and naïve approach would be to decorate your BlockingQueue with an implementation that simply checks the underlying queue and then posts a task to do the notification.

```
NotifyingQueue<T> extends ForwardingBlockingQueue<T> implements BlockingQueue<T> {
  private final Notifier notifier; // injected not null

  …

  @Override public void put(T element) {
    if (getDelegate().isEmpty()) {
      notifier.notEmptyAnymore();
    }
    super.put(element);
  }

  @Override public T poll() {
    final T result = super.poll();
    if ((result != null) && getDelegate().isEmpty())
      notifier.nowEmpty();
  }
  … etc
}
```

This approach though has a couple of problems. While the empty -> notEmpty is pretty straightforward – particularly for a single producer case, it would be easy for two consumers to run concurrently and both see the queue go from non-empty -> empty.

If though, all you want is to be notified that the queue became empty *at some time*, then this will be enough as long as your notifier is your state machine, tracking emptiness and non-emptiness and notifying when it changes from one to the other:

```
AtomicStateNotifier implements Notifier {
  private final AtomicBoolean empty = new AtomicBoolean(true); // assume it starts empty
  private final Notifier delegate; // injected not null

  public void notEmptyAnymore() {
    if (empty.get() && empty.compareAndSet(true, false))
      delegate.notEmptyAnymore();
  }

  public void nowEmpty() {
    if (!empty.get() && empty.compareAndSet(false, true))
      delegate.nowEmpty();
  }
}
```

This is now a thread-safe guard around an actual Notifier implementation that perhaps posts tasks to an Executor to asynchronously write the events to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The design is most likely flawed but you can do it relatively simple:
You have a single thread adding, so you can check before adding. i.e. `pool.getQueue().isEmpty()` - w/ one producer, this is safe.

Last item removed cannot be guaranteed but you can override `beforeExecute` and check the queue again. Possibly w/ a small timeout after `isEmpty()` returns true. Probably the code below will be better off executed in afterExecute instead.

```
protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) { 
  if (getQueue().isEmpty()){
    try{
      Runnable r = getQueue().poll(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      if (r!=null){ 
        execute(r);
      }  else{
        //last message - or on after execute by Setting a threadLocal and check it there
        //alternatively you may need to do so ONLY in after execute, depending on your needs
     }
    }catch(InterruptedException _ie){
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
  }
}
```

sometime like that

I can explain why doing notifications w/ the queue itself won't work well: imagine you add a task to be executed by the pool, the task is scheduled immediately, the queue is empty again and you will need notification.